# React-Bootstrap Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cdn, react-bootstrap

I am new to react, I am trying to use react-bootstrap in  a project. However I could not get it worked, the example on react-bootstrap page at https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html. I only included  below code in my html,  but I am getting **react.production.min.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**  error. Actually I have read other questions and many tutorials, still could not even include correct files from cdn. What should be the correct files or do I need to any other scripts to get it worked.
Thank you,,

```
<!-- Bootsrap and react js-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/cjs/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.5/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Full error trace is below  :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at react.production.min.js:10
 react-bootstrap.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property    'Component' of undefined
at Object.e.__esModule.default (react-bootstrap.min.js:10)
at t (react-bootstrap.min.js:1)
at Object.e.__esModule.default (react-bootstrap.min.js:11)
at t (react-bootstrap.min.js:1)
at Object.t.exports (react-bootstrap.min.js:1)
at t (react-bootstrap.min.js:1)
at t (react-bootstrap.min.js:1)
at react-bootstrap.min.js:1
at react-bootstrap.min.js:1
at react-bootstrap.min.js:1
```

react-dom.production.min.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at react-dom.production.min.js:13
1:86 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactBootstrap is not defined
    at 1:86

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using it in a browser, don't follow the CommonJS section until you are using webpack or something similar. Browsers are asynchronous, therefore you cannot use `require` synchronously. Follow the ES6 (if you are transpiling with Babel) or AMD (with RequireJS or similar) instructions instead.

If you don't know what any of those mean, follow the "Browser globals" instructions to include everything:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/<react-version>/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/<react-version>/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/<version>/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, Actually, I am just including files and errors are coming up in console. Tha whole code about react-bootstrap is those includes, Also I will update the post for full errors.

Comment: @AliinsanSoyaslan I see what you mean, try another CDN link instead: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/mb7m0yd0/ (Look at External Resources in the left)

Comment: I tried to use files from npm(I am new to npm too) and here is another problem. MAybe you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547580/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined-react-bootsrap